# Protractor: element is not getting cleared with clear function

Tags: protractor

I am expecting that the previous value on `firstname` is removed and then I can write the new value. But it is not removing the name.

Clear() function is not helping here.

```
var firstname= element(By.model('subject.firstName'));
firstname.clear().then(function() {
    firstname.sendKeys('bob');
})
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="subject.firstName" 
   placeholder="First Name" name="firstName" validator="required"
   valid-method="submit" message-id="requireFirstName"
   ng-maxlength="50" class="ng-pristine ng-pending ng-empty 
   ng-valid-maxlength ng-touched">
```

Protractor version: 4.0.11

Comment: What are you expecting and what is the actual result

Comment: I am expecting that the previous value on firstname is removed and then I can write the new value. But it is not removing the name.

Comment: can you provide the relevant HTML code or the application URL?

Comment: Please edit your question so that it is clear what you expect and what you are in fact getting.

Comment: Is the element you are trying to clear an `<input>` or `<textarea>` ?  Please post html of element you are trying to clear.

Comment: <input type="text" ng-model="subject.firstName" placeholder="First Name" name="firstName" validator="required" valid-method="submit" message-id="requireFirstName" ng-maxlength="50" class="ng-pristine ng-pending ng-empty ng-valid-maxlength ng-touched">

Comment: Can you pls tell which version of protractor are you using?

Comment: Protractor version:4.0.11

Comment: Try to add extra logging within the then block like `console.log("cleared the text field");`. My current guess is that it skips this entire block of code. Have you also just tried sending the keys bob without clearing?

Comment: @ cnishina: if I send bob without clearing than it will add that text with the current text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I generally add click() event before performing clear() or sendKeys(), just to make sure focus is on element. For example:

```
element(by.model('anyvalue')).click().clear().sendKeys(value);
```

Comment: @rk30: +1. This is working with the click function, is there any other way or trick to get that focus on the element you want to clear ?

Comment: Does not work for me. Here is a workaround for stubborn cases: stackoverflow.com/a/65477389/3021889 (eg. auto-formatted fields or protractor/OS incompatibilities)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have an element with model `anyvalue` on your website.

Change

```
element(By.model...
```

to

```
element(by.model...
```

I believe that you don't have to use `then()` on clear, even though it returns a promise. So you can check if this will work:

```
firstname.clear();
firstname.sendKeys('bob');
```

Comment: Are you sure that your element is visible and page is loaded when `clear()` is executed? You can put `browser.sleep(5000);` before `clear()` just to see if it even has a chance to clear the element.

Comment: Is your website written in Angular?

Comment: Yes. Angular js app

Comment: Update your question and show us your whole test file, all `describe` and everything.

Comment: @FCin: this is not working without the click function to get the focus on the element.